# Solving a differential equation with one parameter defined by another differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a differential equation as below:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=(y-z)x$$

$z$ is constant and $y$ is given by another differential equation as below:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ay$$

$a$ is a constant

How can I solve the equation?

I tried to find the value of $y(t)$ and I substituted that in the $\frac{dx}{dt}$. But I am not sure whether is correct way of doing it. Kindly help.

Comment: What is $z$ here? Is it a constant, variable, or another function?

Answer (score 1):

If $z,a$ are just constants then yes you can solve the second DE :
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ay$$
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{y}=a\int dt \implies \ln y =at+c $$
$$\implies y(t)=ce^{at}$$
Now plug this in the first equation and solve it the same way..
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=(y-z)x$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x}=\int (ce^{at}-z)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a correct way. Once you know the expression of $y(t)$, the first ODE can be solved "as usual".

Answer (score 0):

From the second Eq. $y=e^{at}$, putting in in the first where $z$ is a constant, we get
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=(e^{at}-z)x \implies  \int \frac{dx}{x)= \int (e^{at}- z)dt
\implies \ln x=e^{at}{a}-zt+C.$$ $$ \implies x=\exp[\frac{e^at}{a}-zt+C].$$